# DataGrip - How to view history of all changes made via table editor

Tags: datagrip

I got a very simple question. When editing a table in table editor after I perform a query, I would like to get the query executed, let's say, after I add a row via the editor. This would save me a lot of time.
When I look at the query logs, it only shows me the initial query I used to bring up the table. I need the queries performed after I click the SUBMIT button.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: There is no such feature in DataGrip now. You can share your thoughts here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3571

Comment: Were you looking for console history https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/working-with-database-consoles.html#view-a-console-history

Answer (score 1):

Since 2018.1 version thee is [Data editor SQL log](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/04/03/datagrip-2018-1/#data_editor_sql_log). So now, while updating data you can see which particular queries DataGrip is running.

Comment: For who don't know how to open it: View > Tool Windows > Services (or hotkey: Alt + 8)